# MongoDB: get latest full document for each id by date/time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the latest documents that are in an array of ids based on data/time.  I have the following query that does this, but it only returns the `_id` and `acquiredTime` fields.  How can I get it to return the full document with all the fields?

```
db.trip.aggregate([
   { $match: { tripId: { $in: ["trip01", "trip02" ]}} },
   { $sort: { acquiredTime: -1} },
   { $group: { _id: "$tripId" , acquiredTime: { $first: "$acquiredTime" }}} 
])
```

The collection looks something like:

```
[{
   "tripId": "trip01",
   "acquiredTime": 1000,
   "name": "abc",
   "value": "abc"
},{
   "tripId": "trip02",
   "acquiredTime": 1000,
   "name": "xyz",
   "value": "xyz"
},{
   "tripId": "trip01",
   "acquiredTime": 2000,
   "name": "def",
   "value": "abc"
},{
   "tripId": "trip02",
   "acquiredTime": 2000,
   "name": "ghi",
   "value": "xyz"
}]
```

At the moment I get:

```
[{
   "tripId": "trip01",
   "acquiredTime": 2000
},{
   "tripId": "trip02",
   "acquiredTime": 2000
}]
```

I need to get:

```
[{
   "tripId": "trip01",
   "acquiredTime": 2000,
   "name": "def",
   "value": "abc"
},{
   "tripId": "trip02",
   "acquiredTime": 2000,
   "name": "ghi",
   "value": "xyz"
}]
```

Comment: Since all fields are from one collection I don't think "aggregate" is required, simple "find" will work.

Comment: @Nareshkumar What would "multiple collections" have to do with it? MongoDB does not do anything over multiple collections. If you do not understand why aggregate is needed here then you didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't get the context of using "aggregate" in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is the right approach, but the thing is that [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) just don't work that way and require you to name all of the fields you want in the result.

If you don't mind the structure looking a bit different, then you can always use [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) in MongoDB versions 2.6 and greater:

```js
db.trip.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "tripId": { "$in": ["trip01", "trip02" ]}} },
   { "$sort": { "acquiredTime": -1} },
   { "$group": { "_id": "$tripId" , "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }}} 
])
```

So the whole document is there, but just all contained as a sub-document to "doc" in the results.

For anything else or prettier you are going to have to specify every field that you want. It's just a data structure so you could always generate it from code anyway.

```js
db.trip.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "tripId": { "$in": ["trip01", "trip02" ]}} },
   { "$sort": { "acquiredTime": -1} },
   { "$group": { 
       "_id": "$tripId" , 
       "acquiredTime": { "$first": "$acquiredTime" },
       "name": { "$first": "$name" },
       "value": { "$first": "$value" }
   }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

*To my understading*, the above solution suffers from performance and RAM problems when there is a large number of unique documents to be returned, as the output of $match is sorted in memory, no matter what indices you may have.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

To maximise performance and minimise RAM usage:

- Create a unique index `[(tripId, 1), (acquiredTime, -1)]`
- Have the sort to operate *exactly* along the index

This of course will cost you an index, which will slow down inserts - there's no free meal :)

Additionally, the cosmetic problem of having the original document moved to a sub-document can be easily solved with `$replaceRoot`, without needing to explicltly list the document keys.

```
db.trip.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "tripId": { "$in": ["trip01", "trip02" ]}} },
   { "$sort": SON([("tripId", 1), ("acquiredTime", -1)],
   { "$group": { "_id": "$tripId" , "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }}},
   { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc"}} 
])
```

Finally, it's worth noting that if acquiredTime is just your server time, you can get rid of it, as the `_id` already embeds the creation timestamp. So the unique index would go on `[(tripId, 1), (_id, -1)]`, and the query becomes:

```
db.trip.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "tripId": { "$in": ["trip01", "trip02" ]}} },
   { "$sort": SON([("tripId", 1), ("_id", -1)],
   { "$group": { "_id": "$tripId" , "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }}},
   { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc"}} 
])
```

This is also better as date objects in MongoDB have a resolution of 1 millisecond, which - depending on the frequency of your inserts - may result in extremely hard to reproduce race conditions, whereas auto-generated `_id` are guaranteed to be strictly incremental.